# Apply a function iteratively to pieces of arrays

Tags: matlab, function, accumarray

So I have this cute pretty function which requires two input: price vector and date vector:

```
function   [tsve, timeint, dbin,adjtsve, stringdate,rvavg,rv ] = TSVE( price,datetime )
```

Now I have the vectors price and datetime covering a long period let say 20days and I want to compute the previous function over each day. The number of observations for each day is random but I can easily manage to find the last observation of the day.

```
date=floor(datetime);
[a, b, c]=unique(date,'legacy');   <----This gives me the index for the last obs of the day
[~, nbin]=histc(date,a,1);      <----I was thinking about accumarray so I made this, but I am not sure I can use it on 2 values simultaneously
```

So I was thinking, is there a way to run a function (iteratively) on each piece of the two vectors? or should I split my two vectors into pieces and run the function on each piece?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: you can use `accumarray` with custom function. Use the third output of `unique` as the `subs` input of accumarray.

Comment: @Shai I updated the question. based on that example this should do the trick?  
 `output= accumarray(c,price,[],@(x)TSVE(price,datetime));`

Comment: it's a bit more tricky than that (this is qhy I post it as a comment and not an answer). you'll have to fiddle with it a bit...